# Do Egyptian Citizens need transit visa at Athens International Airport

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, greece, egyptian-citizens

I hold an Egyptian Passport and will book a ticket from Moscow, Russia on Aegean Airlines to Cairo, Egypt. As any foreign airlines I will transit in Athens international Airport for 8 hours, do I need a Schengen transit visa to spend those 8 hours at Athens International Airport. Are the airline hostesses going to make sure that I have such transit visa before they let me on board in Moscow Domodedovo Airport.

Answer (score 0):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers transiting through Athens (ATH)
> and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward
> ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a
> Schengen Member State.

So if your trip is on a single ticket, you don't need a visa.